# Bootstrap: Force cell height to stretch over the remaining screen

Tags: css, html, web, layout, bootstrap-4

I want to use bootstrap 4.0 to create a layout 2 rows x 3 columns layout. I also have a navigation bar which I excluded from this example because it is not necessary.

I want the 2 x 3 layout to stretch the height of the rows evenly over the full remaining screen size without invoking a vertical scrolling bar. At the moment I am using "height: 600px" in the   to control the height of the cells. I think this solution is not good for other devices. Is there a way to achieve this in a relative manner.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>

    <style>
      .my-row {
        height: 600px
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="wrapper container-fluid ">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-stretch my-row">
                <div class="col-md-4">Widget 1</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Widget 2</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Widget 3</div>

                <!-- Force next columns to break to new line -->
                <div class="w-100"></div>

                <div class="col-md-4">Widget 4</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Widget 5</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Widget 6</div>
            </div>
        </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can set height to 100% if your body and your html have their height already set to 100%

Comment: @Neil I replaced 600px by 100% but that did only make the cells smaller.

Comment: in fact, every parent of your .my-row must have height:100%, if it is smaller, it means one parent have a fixed height (wrapper here i think)

Comment: @Neil Where can I check which parent has fixed height?

Comment: in chrome or firefox dev tools, you can highlight tags and see their real height, or if you want you can style your html,body,wrapper,and myrow different background-colors, and see which one doesnt take alkl the space it can